# If $u \in L^\infty(0, T; H) \cap L^2(0, T; V)$ then $(u \cdot \nabla)u \in L^{4/3}(0,T; L^{6/5})$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

Let $H$ be the completion of the space of divergence-free smooth functions with compact support in some bounded set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, and $V = H \cap (H^1_0)^3$. I am following a proof of the following lemma:

> If  $u \in L^\infty(0, T; H) \cap L^2(0, T; V)$ then
> $$(u \cdot \nabla)u \in L^{4/3}(0,T; L^{6/5}).$$

The proof states that using the Holder inequality with exponents $5/3$ and $5/2$,
$$\|(u \cdot \nabla)u\|_{L^{6/5}} \leq \Big(\int |\nabla u|^{6/5} |u|^{6/5}\Big)^{5/6} \tag{1}$$
$$\leq \Big(\int |\nabla u|^2\Big)^{1/2}\Big(\int |u|^3\Big)^{1/3} \tag{2}$$
$$=\|\nabla u\|_{L^2} \|u\|_{L^3} \tag{3}$$
$$\leq \| \nabla u\|_{L^2} \|u\|_{L^2}^{1/2}\|u\|_{L^6}^{1/2} \tag{4}$$
$$\leq c\|u\|_{H^1}^{3/2}\|u\|_{L^2}^{1/2} \tag{5}.$$
Thus,
$$\int_0^T \|(u \cdot \nabla)u\|_{L^{6/5}}^{4/3} \leq c \int_0^T \|u\|_{H^1}^2 \|u\|_{L^2}^{2/3} \tag{6}$$
where the right hand side is finite because $u \in L^\infty(0, T; H) \cap L^2(0, T; H^1)$.

I am new to working with these kind of inequalities. How are (1), (2), (4), and (5) established? In (6), what ensures $\|u\|_{H^1}$ is finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)$: We can prove $|(u \cdot \nabla)u| \le |\nabla u| |u|$ by writing everything out explicitly and using Cauchy-Schwartz:

$$|(u \cdot \nabla)u| \le \sqrt {\sum_{i = 1}^n u_i^2} \sqrt {\sum_{i, j = 1}^n (\partial_i u_j)^2} = |u||\nabla u|$$

$(2)$: I'm not sure where the confusion with this bit is. We apply Holder's with exponents $(5/3, 5/2)$ which yields:

$$\lVert (u \cdot \nabla) u\rVert_{L^{6/5}} \le \left(\int |\nabla u|^{(6/5) \times (5/3)}\right)^{(5/6) \times (3/5)} \left(\int |u|^{(6/5) \times (5/2)}\right)^{(5/6) \times (2/5)}$$

$(4)$: This is Lebesgue interpolation, let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^3$ be measurable, $1 \le p \le r \le q \le \infty$ and $u \in L^p(\Omega) \cap L^q(\Omega)$. Then $u \in L^r(\Omega)$ and further:

$$\lVert u\rVert_{L^r} \le \lVert u\rVert_{L^p}^\alpha \lVert u\rVert_{L^q}^{1 - \alpha}$$
where $\alpha$ satisfies:
$$\frac 1 r = \frac \alpha p + \frac {1 - \alpha} q$$
Here we are applying Lebesgue interpolation with $(p, q,r) = (2, 6, 3)$, and we find $\alpha = 1/2$.

$(5)$: We see that $\lVert \nabla u\rVert_{L^2} \le \lVert u\rVert_{H^1}$ simply since $\lVert u\rVert_{H^1}^2 = \lVert u\rVert_{L^2}^2 + \lVert \nabla u\rVert_{L^2}^2$.

$(6)$: We are given that $u \in L^2(0, T; V)$. So $t \mapsto \lVert u(t)\rVert_V := \lVert u(t)\rVert_{H^1}$ is $L^2$ on $[0, T]$. Also $u \in L^\infty(0, T; H)$, so $t \mapsto \lVert u(t)\rVert_H := \lVert u(t)\rVert_{L^2}$ is $L^\infty$ on $[0, T]$. The last integral is hence finite.

The book *The Three-Dimensional Navier–Stokes Equations* by Robinson, Rodrigo and Sadowski also contains this calculation: Lemma 3.4 on page 74. (though not in any more detail than you've written) I'm not sure if you're currently working through it, but statements of Lebesgue interpolation and a few other things are found in the first chapter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The Robinson book is actually the one I am working through and where this lemma comes from.For (5), I never fully understood the relation between the $H^1$ norm and the gradient, I thought this norm only contains partial derivatives ant the whole gradient? For (6), we know that $t \mapsto \lVert u(t)\rVert_{H^1}$ is in $L^2$ and $t \mapsto \lVert u(t)\rVert_{L^2}$ is in $L^\infty$, but how does that tell us about the integral of their product being finite? I believe much of my trouble is due to my inexperience with vector-valued $L^p$ spaces.

Comment: @CBBAM The steps looked very familiar but wasn't sure if they used a common source or something. With $(5)$, note that by $\lVert \nabla u\rVert_{L^2}^2$ we strictly speaking mean $\sum_{i, j = 1}^3 \lVert \partial_i u_j\rVert_{L^2}^2$. (I miscopied my notes with $(1)$, sorry) With $(6)$, since $t \mapsto \lVert u(t)\rVert_{L^2}$ is in $L^\infty$, it is bounded above by some constant $M$, which we can then pull out of the integral.

Comment: I understand now, thank you for all your help!

Comment: If I may ask one more related question, on the same page on the text it says that it follows from this lemma and the Holder inequality that $\int_0^T \langle(u \cdot \nabla)u, v\rangle < \infty$ for all $v \in L^4(0,T; L^6)$. How does the Holder inequality imply this? I am still getting used to working with these kinds of inequalities.

Comment: I should add that I see how $\|(u \cdot \nabla)u v\|_{L_1} \leq \|(u\cdot\nabla u) u\|_{L^{4/3}} \|v\|_{L^4}$ by Holder's inequality. However, how is it justified to change the order of integration in space and time? Second, why do we require that $v$ takes values in $L^6$? Is there some generalized Holder's inequality for Bochner spaces?